# lucene documents disappeared (index size shrinks)

Tags: lucene

I have a cluster of servers indexing documents with Lucene indexes located on a network drive. I synchronize IndexWriter creation so only one instance at a time. There are about 50 documents added to the index every second so the index is actively updated.  But within a day or so, the index suddenly shrinks in size, reducing from a few GB to almost empty, then starts growing again.  It appears to be that all documents in the index are suddenly deleted and a new index is been built.  I checked the index with Luke and I could not find any documents labelled as deleted.  I have not been able to catch exactly when this happens.  But when this happens, all the files in the index directly have a new timestamp within the past few minutes, except the write.lock file, which has the time stamp when the index was first created.  There is no any error in indexing and the indexes (before and after the size shrunk) are normal (searchable).

Has anyone seen anything like this?  Any idea what is causing this behavior?  I am using Lucene 6.1 on Windows Server 2012.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Check for somewhere in your code that you are using [`IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode.CREATE`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode.html#CREATE). Opening the index with that open mode will delete the old index and start a new one.

Comment: I created IndexWriterConfig as new IndexWriterConfig(analyzer).  The open mode is not set explicitly.  The default is OpenMode.CREATE_OR_APPEND.  I am wondering if it is possible that somehow Lucene thinks the directory has no index so it creates a new one.  The symptom does look like a new index was created.  I will change the implementation to explicitly set mode to APPEND to see if this fixes the problem.  Thank you very much for the suggestion!